# angular js - new changes in the code are not executed

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular js.

I have observed that new code blocks written in Angular js module file or controllers does not get executed sometimes and when the web site is refreshed surprisingly the code blocks get executed.

1. Is there any Angular js function to force the execution of code?
2. Is there a maximum limit in count of lines of code that can be executed?

Comment: Could you please share the code?

Comment: Did you try clearing your browsers cache?

Comment: Question: Could you please share the code?

Answer: The code is quite simple. In a certain line of the original code there was syntax issues/bug because of which the original code was not giving desired output. In order to trace the bug, I added some diagnostic code, which was not getting executed.

Comment: Question: Did you try clearing your browser cache?
Answer: No, I will try.

Comment: In Chrome, press F12. On the left top part of the browser, right click on refresh and use Clear Cache and hard reload.

Answer (score 1):

It might be because of browser caching.

In each html template just add the following meta-tags at the top-

```
 <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
 <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
 <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

Or you can simply disable caching from Dev Tools.

Comment: You just killed performance for the production. It's bad idea to give such suggestions without warnings

Comment: Yeah that's true. But there is performance issue with all the solutions that I have come across for this problem, because almost all of them involve busting the cache even when there are no changes made.

Comment: In most of the cases, you just need to configure your server properly. For dev env server should intercept the request and add no-cache header on the fly. For the prod, this should be opt out. For clearing cache with new deployment, hashing strategy used. This should cover 90% of the issues.